# how to find the roots of the following floor-equation:

Tags: roots

How to find the roots of  $$\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor 2x\rfloor+\lfloor 3x\rfloor=6$$

Comment: Hint: We must have $x\ge 1$, for $\lfloor w\rfloor\le w$ for all $w$. And $x=4/3$ is (barely) too big.

Comment: I have a complete solution, but   can't post it as an answer since the question has been closed. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3):

As my previous solution was not complete i would like to write a new one.

Let assume $\left\lfloor   x \right\rfloor=n$  so that we know $n\le x<n+1$ and let $\delta$ the fractional part of x, so that $\delta \epsilon \left( 0,1 \right) $ then
$$\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor +\left\lfloor 2x \right\rfloor +\left\lfloor 3x \right\rfloor =6\quad \Longrightarrow \quad \left\lfloor n+\delta  \right\rfloor +\left\lfloor 2\left( n+\delta  \right)  \right\rfloor +\left\lfloor 3\left( n+\delta  \right)  \right\rfloor =6$$
obviosly,it is equal to $$\left\lfloor n+\delta  \right\rfloor +\left\lfloor 2n+2\delta  \right\rfloor +\left\lfloor 3n+3\delta  \right\rfloor =6$$

Due to the fact that $n$,$2n$ and $3n$  is an integer we can write it as follows:

$$n+\left\lfloor \delta  \right\rfloor +2n+\left\lfloor 2\delta  \right\rfloor +3n+\left\lfloor 3\delta  \right\rfloor =6$$
Now,there are three sub-cases,i.e. we will divide $\left( 0,1 \right) $ in to three parts by $\delta $:

**$1$**.If $0\le \delta <\frac { 1 }{ 3 }   $ then
$$
\left\lfloor n+\delta  \right\rfloor +\left\lfloor 2n+2\delta  \right\rfloor +\left\lfloor 3n+3\delta  \right\rfloor =6
      \Rightarrow  n+2n+3n=6    \Rightarrow  n=1     $$
so

$$1\le x<\frac { 4 }{ 3 } $$

**$2.$** If $\frac { 1 }{ 3 } \le \delta <\frac { 2 }{ 3 } $ then 
$$
n+\left\lfloor \delta  \right\rfloor +2n+\left\lfloor 2\delta  \right\rfloor +3n+\left\lfloor 3\delta  \right\rfloor =6 \Rightarrow 
n+2n+3n+1=6   \Rightarrow  n=\frac { 5 }{ 6 } 
$$ 
but n should be integer

**$3.$** If $\frac { 2 }{ 3 } \le \delta <1$ then 
$$
n+\left\lfloor \delta  \right\rfloor +2n+\left\lfloor 2\delta  \right\rfloor +3n+\left\lfloor 3\delta  \right\rfloor =6 \Rightarrow 
n+2n+1+3n+2=6   \Rightarrow  n=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } 
$$ in that case n is not integer either. 
So our final answer is

> $$1\le x<\frac { 4 }{ 3 } $$

Comment: for EX. if x=4/3 Equality  is not true.